# How can I display the required screen depending on whether the user is authorized or not using the package auto_route: ^7.8.0?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, auto-route

I use the navigation package auto_route: ^7.8.0.
How can I use it to display the initial login page, depending on whether the user is logged in to firebase or not?

**main.dart**

```
final _appRouter = AppRouter();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GlobalBlocInjector(
      child: MaterialApp.router(
        localizationsDelegates: const [
          S.delegate,
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
        routerConfig: _appRouter.config(
          reevaluateListenable: ReevaluateListenable.stream(FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()),
          navigatorObservers: () => [
            TalkerRouteObserver(GetIt.I<Talker>()),
          ],
        ),
        locale: const Locale('ru'),
        supportedLocales: S.delegate.supportedLocales,
        theme: const DarkThemeBuilder().build(),
        scaffoldMessengerKey: GetIt.instance<SnackBarService>(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**app_router.dart**

```
import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';
import '../../presentation/presentation.dart';
import '../app.dart';

part 'router.gr.dart';

@AutoRouterConfig()
class AppRouter extends _$AppRouter {


  @override
  List<AutoRoute> get routes => [
        AutoRoute(page: SignInRoute.page, initial: true,),
        AutoRoute(page: SignUpRoute.page),
        AutoRoute(page: MainRoute.page),
        AutoRoute(page: ResetPasswordRoute.page),
        AutoRoute(page: ChangePasswordRoute.page),
        AutoRoute(page: ReVerificationRoute.page),
      ];
}
```

I tried to follow the documentation listed on pub.dev, but unfortunately nothing comes out

```
@AutoRouterConfig()
class AppRouter extends $AppRouter implements AutoRouteGuard {
  @override
  void onNavigation(NavigationResolver resolver, StackRouter router) {
      if(isAuthenticated || resolver.route.name == LoginRoute.name){
         // we continue navigation
          resolver.next();
      }else{
          // else we navigate to the Login page so we get authenticateed
          
          // tip: use resolver.redirect to have the redirected route
          // automatically removed from the stack when the resolver is completed
          resolver.redirect(LoginRoute(onResult:(didLogin)=> resolver.next(didLogin)))
      }
   }
  // ..routes[]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check for

```
if(snapshot.hasData)
{
  //Got to homepage
}
else
{
// got to Login page
}
```

This is way easier to implement.